# Jquery method to get back text like a node

Tags: jquery

I am working on a blog and I would like to use jquery effects to make a validated post disappear from a textarea and then make it appear above the textarea in the post flow, like this:

```
//html 

...
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
...

<div class="invisible">
<div id="targetting"></div>
<div>
//script

$('#my-btn').click(function() {
    var comment = $('#textarea').val();
    $('.targetting:last').text(comment);

    var m = {$id};
    var data = {
          comment: $('#propo-textarea-spec').val(),
          m: {$id}
        };

        $.post('index.php?',data,function(callback_data){

        var content = $('div.my-btn').html();
        $('div .comments').append(content);


        var textarea=$('#textarea').val();
        $('textarea').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $('.my-effect').fadeIn(800);
            $('.my-effect:last').css("display","none");

        });


   });
  });
```

But the fade out effect makes my textarea disappear entirely (which is logical). I tried `.text()` and it didn't work. My question is this: what is the jquery method to get the textarea message back like a node?

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $('#textarea').val();
$('#textarea').parent().append( '<span class="blahnode">' ).html(content);
```

would do what you want, if I understand your correctly.

Comment: In fact this doesn't really work : the whole textarea disappears with the fadeOut effect...

Comment: You need to do this before you get rid of the textarea if you're fading it out (get the content then at least), and add the span directly to the parent of the textarea.

Comment: This is what I did : first I append the comment, then I fadeOut the text of the textarea, and finally I fadeIn the new post